# Silverlight 4 Binding and SilverlightBindingWrapper

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a class that represents a container and a class that represents things that can go in that container, as well as a user control that displays that container and a user control that displays things that can go in that container, something like

```
public class MyContainer
{
    public MyThing Thing1
    { 
        get { return thing1; }
        set
        {
            if (thing1 != value)
            {
                thing1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Thing1");
            }
        }
    }
}


<UserControl x:Class="MyContainerControl"
    ...
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        ...
        <ctl:MyThingControl DataContext="{Binding Thing1}" />
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Designer complains about `{Binding Thing1}` with the error message

> unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.InstanceBuilders.SilverlightBindingWrapper'
>   to type 'MyThing'

However, if I set the data context in code behind, everything works fine.

What does this error mean, and how can I resolve the data binding issue?